# ASP.net c# Windows Authentication - With optional login for users logged into generic accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, authentication

I am building an intranet page to log requests within our organisation.  This is currently using *Windows authentication* to authenticate the users and get their roles from Active Directory.

This works great for most situations, however there are certain computers which will need to use this which are logged into generic accounts not assigned to any individual people.

These accounts are all stored within a particular group in Active Directory so I could easily check if a user is logging on via a generic account and then redirect them to a login page of some kind which will then prompt them to log in with their windows account details.

**Can this be done?**  I have spent all day trying to get it to work but failed.  I have looked through the below article which gives me a login page which only allows users to log in with correct credentials, however when users have logged in, it still shows the generic and details and roles on the site rather than pulling through the newly logged on user.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37558/Windows-Authentication-Using-Form-Authentication

I have also tried Windows Authentication Impersonate but this does not seem to work across the whole site and instead just on a single page.  Any help/guidance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain "...it still shows my username and details on the site". If you are logged in a machine with generic account, I would think from your explanation, it would be the generic user info.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain myself very well there. Yes I meant that it still shows the generic login details with their access rights and roles etc and not the new user which was trying to log in. I have edited the text above thank you.

Comment: What code are you using to get user info? What value do you see for HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name?

Comment: I am using HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name as you say.  I know it's not working because I have the name of the current user displayed in the header of the site.  The site menu is also hooked up to display different options based on what security groups the user is a part of on active directory. This is not affected when the user logs in.

Comment: What does your web.config authentication/authorization sections look like?

Comment: I have tried doing this demo just on its own instead of trying to incorporate the code into my own site and it seems to work ok, although really this is not exactly what I am looking for.  I am really pushed for time on this so I am going to instead display a message asking users to log off and then back on if they are on generic accounts and then come back to this when I have some more time. Thank you very much for all of the help you have given so far it has been much appreciated.